# Как в инпут радио получить значение из обьекта , которое будет отображаться на экране

Tags: javascript

Код:

```js
let Input11 = document.getElementById('11')

const Quiz_Obj = {
    Seventh_Question: {
        text: '5! ?',
        option: [5,25,120,125]
    },
}

Input11.innerHTML = Quiz_Obj.Seventh_Question.text
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
  key: 'value'
}

l.textContent = obj.key;

О чем писали выше в комментариях
```

```html
 <input type="radio" id="r">
 <label id="l" for="r">default value</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

У инпутов нет свойства `innerHTML`, зато есть `value`

Comment: а если input type='radio' ?

Comment: Что не ясно в предложении "У инпутов нет свойства innerHTML, зато есть value"?

Comment: Для радио инпута, если нужно чтобы значение ещё и пользователь видел - нужно заносить не тоьлко в инпут, но и в какой-нибудь label  к нему привязанный, или любой другой html элемент.